# How to extract data from matplotlib plot

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have a `wxPython` program which reads from different datasets, performs various types of simple on-the-fly analysis on the data and plots various combinations of the datasets to `matplotlib` canvas. I would like to have the opportunity to dump currently plotted data to file for more sophisticated analysis later on.

The question is: are there any methods in `matplotlib` that allow access to the data currently plotted in `matplotlib.Figure`?

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Jakub is right about modifying the Python script to write out the data directly from the source from which it was sent into the plot; that's the way I'd prefer to do this. But for reference, if you do need to get data out of a plot, I think this should do it

```
gca().get_lines()[n].get_xydata()
```

Alternatively you can get the x and y data sets separately:

```
line = gca().get_lines()[n]
xd = line.get_xdata()
yd = line.get_ydata()
```

Comment: Thanks, I think that should do it. If you want to know the reasons why I prefer dumping data from plot to messing with data sources, please see my comment to @Jacub.

Comment: Why doesn't a `mpl_toolkits.mplot3d.art3d.Line3D object` have `get_zdata()`? I can't extract the z values. :-(

Comment: @SibbsGambling That you'd have to take up with the developers of matplotlib.

Answer (score 9):

The **`matplotlib.pyplot.gca`** can be used to extract data from matplotlib plots. Here is a simple example:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.plot([1,2,3],[4,5,6])
ax = plt.gca()
line = ax.lines[0]
line.get_xydata()
```

On running this, you will see 2 outputs - the plot and the data:

```
array([[1., 4.],
   [2., 5.],
   [3., 6.]])
```

[image]

You can also get the x data and y data seperately.
On running `line.get_xdata()`, you will get:

```
array([1, 2, 3])
```

And on running `line.get_ydata()`, you will get:

```
array([4, 5, 6])
```

**Note:** `gca` stands for *get current axis*

Answer (score 5):

To sum up, for future reference:

If plotting with `plt.plot()` or `plt.stem()` or `plt.step()` you can get a list of Line2D objects with:

```
ax = plt.gca() # to get the axis
ax.get_lines()
```

For `plt.pie()`, `plt.bar()` or `plt.barh()` you can get a list of wedge or rectangle objects with:

```
ax = plt.gca() # to get the axis
ax.patches()
```

Then, depending on the situation you can get the data by running `get_xdata()`, `get_ydata()` (see [Line2D](https://matplotlib.org/3.2.2/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.lines.Line2D.html?highlight=get_xdata#matplotlib.lines.Line2D.get_xdata)) for more info.

or i.e `get_height()` for a bar plot (see [Rectangle](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.patches.Rectangle.html?highlight=get_width#matplotlib.patches.Rectangle.get_width)) for more info.

In general for all basic plotting functions, you can find what you are looking for by running [ax.get_children()](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.get_children.html#matplotlib.axes.Axes.get_children)

that returns a list of the children `Artists` (the base class the includes all of the figure's elements).

Answer (score 1):

Its Python, so you can modify the source script directly so the data is dumped before it is plotted

Comment: I know that's the most pythonic way :) But first, the data is sent to plot from many places and is modified while on the plot; I would need to keep track of every modification of the plotted data. And second - I don't need to dump the data *every time* it is plotted. I would like first to find something interesting and then press a button on NavigationToolbar to export it to file. NavigationToolbar is linked to FigureCanvas, so the buttons have seamless access to Figure properties and methods. That's why I asked how to dump the data from plot.

Comment: This would only work if the user knows beforehand that they want to export the data and the data is static. Rare I would say.

Comment: while this answer is a general good advice, it is not a good answer to the question

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old question, but I feel there is a solution better than the ones offered here so I decided to write this answer.

You can use `unittest.mock.patch` to temporarily replace the `matplotlib.axes.Axes.plot` function:

```
from unittest.mock import patch

def save_data(self, *args, **kwargs):
    # save the data that was passed into the plot function
    print(args)

with patch('matplotlib.axes.Axes.plot', new=save_data):
    # some code that will eventually plot data
    a_function_that_plots()
```

Once you exit the `with` block, `Axes.plot` will resume normal behavior.

Comment: Brilliant, just brilliant! Should be the accepted answer in 2021

Comment: How do I get the data into memory without writing to file? The `with` kills it. `global`? :\

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out in the answer by @mobiuscreek, the way to extract data from axis depends on the function used for plotting: e.g., `ax.get_lines()` would work for a plot created via `ax.plot()`, but it gives an empty array, if the lines were created, e.g., using [`matplotlib.collections.LineCollection`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/shapes_and_collections/line_collection.html). (It is likely to be more of a problem when the figures are created by a third-party code.)

The general approach is then using `ax.get_children()` and parsing it as needed. See, e.g., [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37842148/6151828).

Answer (score 0):

The reason [it is suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8939010/5059838) to just get the data "from the source from which it was sent into the plot" is [because](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7821518/save-plot-to-numpy-array) all matplotlib approaches need `frombuffer canvas tostring_rgb()/buffer_rgba()` hoopla and additionally can cause UB after that because matplotlib behaves differently on different platforms(matplotlib backends)

It's also turns out to be very slow

I just wrote my own in-numpy plotter that plots everything in vectorized way, doesn't have a single critical path loop and is at least 100x faster then the matplotlib hoopla.

https://github.com/bedbad/justpyplot

```
import numpy as np 
import cv2
import time
import justpyplot as jplt

xs, ys = [], []
while(cv2.waitKey(1) != 27):
    xt = time.perf_counter() - t0
    yx = np.sin(xt)
    xs.append(xt)
    ys.append(yx)
    
    frame = np.full((500,470,3), (255,255,255), dtype=np.uint8)
    
    vals = np.array(ys)

    plotted_in_array = jplt.just_plot(frame, vals,title="sin() from Clock")
    
    cv2.imshow('np array plot', plotted_in_array)
```