# How to extract data from plt.imshow() or plt.matshow()?

Tags: python, matplotlib, visualization

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 

data = np.random.random((10,10))
im = plt.imshow(data)
plt.axis('off')
plt.savefig("question2.png",bbox_inches='tight',pad_inches=0)
plt.show()
```

[image]

How to extract data from plt.imshow() or plt.matshow()?

Comment: What do you mean by "extract data". You are defining the data yourself. `data = np.random.random((10,10))`

Comment: A similar question:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8938449/how-to-extract-data-from-matplotlib-plot

Currenly, I have a float 2-D array, which is mapped to a 3-channel image through plt.matshow(). I want to get the data in the 3 channels. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To get RGBA array of the image you plotted on a matplotlib axes, firstly, you grab the image object (here `im3`). Secondly, get its colormap (here `ccmap`). And the final step, pass the data array, `im3._A`, to `ccmap`.

```
import matplotlib.cm as cm
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 

data = np.random.random((10,10))
# imshow or matshow is OK
#im3 = plt.imshow(data, cmap="viridis_r")  #any colormap will do
im3 = plt.matshow(data, cmap="viridis_r")
plt.axis('off')
#plt.savefig("question2.png",bbox_inches='tight',pad_inches=0)
plt.show()

# get the colormap used by the previous imshow()
ccmap = im3.get_cmap() #it is a function
print(ccmap.name)  # 'viridis_r'

# get the image data ***YOU ASK FOR THIS***
# the data is passed to the colormap function to get its original state
img_rgba_array = ccmap(im3._A)

# plot the image data
ax = plt.subplot(111)
ax.imshow(img_rgba_array);  #dont need any cmap to plot
```

Sample output plots:

[image: img_data]

Comment: Amazing! This is exactly what I need!

Hi swatchai, I really appreciate your help :  )

Comment: @brucelau The correct way of appreciation is accepting my answer. :)

Comment: Sure. I'm glad about that : )

Comment: @brucelau To save `minimum` data to file you can save only `data` and the colormap name. The RGBA can be reconstructed from them.

Comment: you mean that we can define a function f, then reconstruct rbga = f(data) to get the values, right?

Comment: @brucelau Yes, all matplotlib colormaps are such function.  Note the use of it, `ccmap(im3._A)` in my code.