# Making a list from data points which already have been plotted

Tags: python, list, plot

I'm trying to list the data points/lines that i already plotted but i can't get it to work. I tried several things but unfortunatly without results.

What i want is that i get a list of the data points that i just plotted. After that i want to be able to create multiple lines with the help of the list instead of all tiny lines what happens now. the plotting is done in these two lines:

this one plots vertical lines
`ax.plot([i+1.5,i+1.5], [j+.5,j+1.5], linewidth=3,linestyle='-',color='#000000')`

and this one plots horizontal lines
 `ax.plot([i+.5,i+1.5], [j+1.5,j+1.5], linewidth=3,linestyle='-',color='#000000')`

can anybody help me out?
below is a part of my code.

````
for iIsochrone in range(int(np.nanmin(array)),int(np.nanmax(array)), Wavelinetime):
        #zorgt voor golflijn met stappen van 10 vertikaal
        for i in range(fileObject.numberOfColumnsInArray-1):
            for j in range(fileObject.numberOfRowsInArray):
                if (array[j, i]<=iIsochrone and array[j, i+1]>iIsochrone) or (array[j, i]>iIsochrone and array[j, i+1]<=iIsochrone):
                   ax.plot([i+1.5,i+1.5], [j+.5,j+1.5], linewidth=3,linestyle='-',color='#000000') #rechte blockline         
        #zorgt voor golflijn met stappen van 10 horizontaal
        for i in range(fileObject.numberOfColumnsInArray):
            for j in range(fileObject.numberOfRowsInArray-1):
                if (array[j, i]<=iIsochrone and array[j+1, i]>iIsochrone) or (array[j, i]>iIsochrone and array[j+1, i]<=iIsochrone):
                    ax.plot([i+.5,i+1.5], [j+1.5,j+1.5], linewidth=3,linestyle='-',color='#000000') #rechte blockline```
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As detailed in [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8938449/how-to-extract-data-from-matplotlib-plot), you could use the `get_lines()` method to extract data points from your plot

`gca().get_lines()[n].get_xydata()`

**EDIT:**

Another option would be to save the values *before* they are being plotted.

For instance, since you are working with lists, you could save your **i** values to a list called **mylisti** and your **j** values to another list called **mylistj**:

````
mylisti=[]
mylistj=[]

for iIsochrone in range(int(np.nanmin(array)),int(np.nanmax(array)), Wavelinetime):
        #zorgt voor golflijn met stappen van 10 vertikaal
        for i in range(fileObject.numberOfColumnsInArray-1):
            for j in range(fileObject.numberOfRowsInArray):
                if (array[j, i]<=iIsochrone and array[j, i+1]>iIsochrone) or (array[j, i]>iIsochrone and array[j, i+1]<=iIsochrone):
                   mylisti+=[i+1.5,i+1.5]
                   mylistj+=[j+.5,j+1.5]
                   ax.plot([i+1.5,i+1.5], [j+.5,j+1.5], linewidth=3,linestyle='-',color='#000000') #rechte blockline         
        #zorgt voor golflijn met stappen van 10 horizontaal
        for i in range(fileObject.numberOfColumnsInArray):
            for j in range(fileObject.numberOfRowsInArray-1):
                if (array[j, i]<=iIsochrone and array[j+1, i]>iIsochrone) or (array[j, i]>iIsochrone and array[j+1, i]<=iIsochrone):
                    ax.plot([i+.5,i+1.5], [j+1.5,j+1.5], linewidth=3,linestyle='-',color='#000000') #rechte blockline```
````

Comment: i tried to use that post but i get the error that my list indez is out of range. i used n=0 to be sure that he picked a line but even with n=0 i got this error

Comment: I suggest another solution in my edited answer. Hope this helps!