# extracting values from tuple object

Tags: python, signal-processing

in python, the `specgram` function gives me a plot of the spectrogram for a given signal. I was wondering how do i save this spectrogram image as a `numpy` array.?

http://matplotlib.org/api/mlab_api.html#matplotlib.mlab.specgram

Comment: I think you're going to need to give more details ... What is specgram?  Where did that function come from?  What types of objects does it return?  How does all of this relate to your question title?

Comment: @mgilson presumably [this one](http://matplotlib.org/api/mlab_api.html#matplotlib.mlab.specgram)...

Comment: yes. this one. edited the question.

Comment: The question title is confusing. Maybe you mean same as [Matplotlib: save plot to numpy array](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7821518/222914)