# matplotlib: render into buffer / access pixel data

Tags: python, opengl, matplotlib

I want to use plots generated with matplotlib as textures in OpenGL. The OpenGL backends for matplotlib I came across so far are either immature or discontinued, so I want to avoid them.

My current approach is to save figures into temporary .png files from which I assemble texture atlases. However, I would prefer to avoid storing intermediate files and get pixel data directly from matplotlib instead. Is this possible somehow?

---

The answer I was looking for is `fig.canvas.print_to_buffer()`. Joe's answer contains other alternatives worth checking out.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Sure, just use [`fig.canvas.tostring_rgb()`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/backend_agg_api.html#matplotlib.backends.backend_agg.FigureCanvasAgg.tostring_rgb) to dump the rgb buffer to a string.

Similarly, there's [`fig.canvas.tostring_argb()`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/backend_agg_api.html#matplotlib.backends.backend_agg.FigureCanvasAgg.tostring_argb) if you need the alpha channel, as well.

If you want to dump the buffer to a file, there's `fig.canvas.print_rgb` and  [`fig.canvas.print_rgba`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/backend_agg_api.html#matplotlib.backends.backend_agg.FigureCanvasAgg.print_rgba) (or equivalently, [`print_raw`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/backend_agg_api.html#matplotlib.backends.backend_agg.FigureCanvasAgg.print_raw), which is rgba).

You'll need to draw the figure before dumping the buffer with `tostring*`.  (i.e. do `fig.canvas.draw()` before calling `fig.canvas.tostring_rgb()`)

Just for fun, here's a rather silly example:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

def main():
    t = np.linspace(0, 4*np.pi, 1000)
    fig1, ax = plt.subplots()
    ax.plot(t, np.cos(t))
    ax.plot(t, np.sin(t))

    inception(inception(fig1))
    plt.show()

def fig2rgb_array(fig):
    fig.canvas.draw()
    buf = fig.canvas.tostring_rgb()
    ncols, nrows = fig.canvas.get_width_height()
    return np.fromstring(buf, dtype=np.uint8).reshape(nrows, ncols, 3)

def inception(fig):
    newfig, ax = plt.subplots()
    ax.imshow(fig2rgb_array(fig))
    return newfig

main()
```

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Thank you for pointing me in that direction. There is a `fig.canvas.print_to_buffer()` which seems to be exactly what I'm looking for!

Comment: Joe, is there a way to NOT display on screen the first 2 of the 3 subplots?

Comment: @JamesSynge - Sure, just clear the figure each time you grab its contents.  As a fun example (I wrote this when I originally wrote the answer): https://gist.github.com/joferkington/9138655

Comment: @JoeKington, thanks.  Matplotlib has so many options, I didn't find clf (I did search for clear, but didn't think of clf).

Comment: I'm struggling for some time now, to have exactly the data range but not the frame in the array. Any hints?

Comment: fig.canvas.tostring_rgb() and others are deprecated