# Extract RGBA array from Figure matplotlib

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, plot, waveform

I have the following code which creates a waveform of an audio file:

```
times = np.arange(len(data))/float(samplerate)
fig = plot.figure(figsize = (8,4), frameon = False)
axes = fig.gca()
if(channels == 1): #mono file
    axes.fill_between(times, data, color = 'k')
else: #stereo file
    axes.fill_between(times, data[:,0], data[:,1], color = 'k')

plot.savefig(savefile, dpi = 'figure', transparent = True)
```

I have tried multiple methods to extract the RGBA array from this figure however none have been successful. My current code is below:

```
canvas.draw()       # draw the canvas, cache the renderer

width, height = fig.get_size_inches() * fig.get_dpi()
waveformRGBA= np.fromstring(canvas.tostring_rgb(),dtype='uint8').reshape(height, width, 3)
print waveformRGBA
```

This method produces a blank RGBA array of [255,255,255]

Any ideas???

Comment: Your "current code" doesn't show how `canvas` is created.  That might be helpful to know.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [matplotlib: render into buffer / access pixel data](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21939658/matplotlib-render-into-buffer-access-pixel-data)

Comment: I see you used almost (but not exactly) the same commands as in the answer to the question linked above. Does the example in that answer work for you neither? Otherwise try to fix the differences.

Answer (score 1):

To read the RGB and alpha from a png file:

```
from scipy import misc
im = misc.imread("figure.png")
```

In this case `im` is a 3D array  (rows x columns x 4) with the RGB and alpha information for each pixel of a figure with dimensions rows x columns.