# matplotlib savefig() looks worse than show()

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, graph

I can't reproduce the same plot quality shown with matplotlib `plt.show()` in `plt.savefig()`. I have followed [this thread here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7906365/matplotlib-savefig-plots-different-from-show) but no luck. As indicated there, I have created anew the `matplotlibrc.template` in the newly created `.matplotlib` folder, and changed the suggested parameters. I have also tried to change the dpi value, from some very high input manually selected (e.g., `dpi=1200`) to that passed from the original figure (`dpi=fig.dpi`). I have also tried to change the resulting extension of the save files: eps/png/pdf (eps would be preferrable). None of this really fixed the issue. I suspect there might be some conflicts between settings but I am not sure where to look for.

Comment: I am not sure if this would solve the problem, but you can also try to save the picture to a numpy array first and then convert it to a PIL image and then save. (Assuming the problem is with matplotlib.) This is how to make the conversion to numpy array: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21939658/matplotlib-render-into-buffer-access-pixel-data and this is how to convert from numpy array to PIL image: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10965417/how-to-convert-a-numpy-array-to-pil-image-applying-matplotlib-colormap. To save the PIL image there is a PIL function called `.save()`.

Comment: @p479h thanks. I have doing a similar workaround, by saving the image plotted by `show()`, but this is not the solution I had in mind.

Comment: Sorry. I can't think of much else.