# buffer_rgba() mysteriously adds whitespace to matplotlib figure

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have some simple code in a notebook to visualize an image with matplotlib

```
f = plt.figure()
plt.imshow(rgb_img)
# f.tight_layout(pad=0) doesn't fix the issue
f.canvas.draw()
# save figure as a np array for easy visualization w/ imshow later
fig_as_np_array = np.array(f.canvas.renderer.buffer_rgba())
```

At this point everything looks fine:

[image]

I then try to view the saved np array (`plt.imshow(fig_as_np_array)`) which I expect to display the same thing but instead I get odd whitespace plus a new sets of axis:

[image]

I can't for the life of me figure out what is adding the extra whitespace/axis, the shapes are slightly different as well:

```
print(f'rgb shape: {rgb_img.shape}') # prints: rgb shape: (480, 640, 3)
print(f'saved fig shape: {fig_as_np_array.shape}') # prints: saved fig shape: (288, 432, 4)
```

Any idea what is going on (fwiw I am visualizing this in a notebook). Thanks for your time

Comment: `fig_as_np_array` is, as you correctly named it, the WHOLE FIGURE, not just the content of the Axes object. The size (shape) depends on the size and dpi value of your figure (`rcParams['figure.figsize']` and `plt.rcParams['figure.dpi']`)

Comment: Thanks @Stef but I still can't remove the whitspace. I've tried setting all the params that I think are relevant:

```plt.rcParams['figure.subplot.bottom'] = 0
plt.rcParams['figure.subplot.wspace'] = 0
plt.rcParams['figure.subplot.left'] = 0
plt.rcParams['figure.subplot.right'] = 1``` but there is no change on the the imshow result

Comment: I can't quite grasp your thought process. You have the image you want to display. Then you display it. Then you save the whole figure and display that, even though all you wanted was to display the image you already had in the first place. What exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: @user8408080, sorry for the confusion. Fundamentally I want to add some labels to the image (ie plt.text(), etc.) and then save the image w/ the labels as a numpy array so that I can save it to disk and visualize later.

Before I do that, I want to understand how to control the figure so that it doesn't add whitespace I cant control around the image. Ideally I just want the image to fully take up the figure

Comment: This could be a [XY-Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem). Do you *really* want to rasterize all objects in the figure, work on that and re-rasterize again? Or do you maybe just want to save the figure object? Why do you even need to save the figure in between; maybe you could do all the steps in one script?

Comment: I need to save my figure (which includes the image, the text written on it, etc) into an ```np.array``` b/c that is the only format my image viewer accepts (it is running on a remote server and reads only ```np.array``` out of a file to display images

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If I understood your question correctly, you'll have to ensure to create the figure with the correct dimensions and then remove the axes (via `ax.set_axis_off()`) and the frame of the figure around the image (via `frameon=False`) before writing to buffer, see the comments below:

```
import matplotlib as mpl
mpl.use("tkagg") # <— you may not need this, 
                 #    but I had to specify an agg backend manually
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.image as mpimg
import numpy as np

## image taken from
# "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/5/5e/Empty_road_at_night.jpg/1024px-Empty_road_at_night.jpg"
filename = "1024px-Empty_road_at_night.jpg"
im = mpimg.imread(filename)

## create the figure with the correct dpi & resolution
#  and make sure that you specify to show "no frame" around the image
figure_dpi = 72
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(1024/figure_dpi,768/figure_dpi),dpi=figure_dpi,frameon=False,facecolor="w")
ax = fig.add_subplot()

## turn of axes, make imshow use the whole frame
ax.set_axis_off()
plt.subplots_adjust(top = 1, bottom = 0, right = 1, left = 0, hspace = 0, wspace = 0)
plt.margins(0,0)

## show image
ax.imshow(im,zorder=0,alpha=1.0,origin="upper")
## add some text label
ax.text(300,600,"this is the middle lane",fontsize=30,color="w")

def fig2rgb_array(fig):
    """adapted from: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21939658/"""
    fig.canvas.draw()
    buf = fig.canvas.tostring_rgb()
    ncols, nrows = fig.canvas.get_width_height()
    print("to verify, our resolution is: ",ncols,nrows)
    return np.frombuffer(buf, dtype=np.uint8).reshape(nrows, ncols, 3)

## make a new figure and read from buffer
fig2,ax2 = plt.subplots()
ax2.imshow(fig2rgb_array(fig))
plt.show()
```

yields (note there is now only *one* set of axes around the image, not two):

[image: buffered image with text on top]

Comment: Thank you so much! Let me recreate the bounty so I can give it to you!

Comment: Also I did realize I had my W and H variables flipped in ```figsize``` which was exacerbating the problem