# Is it possible to access the rasterized representation of a matplotlib Artist?

Tags: python, matplotlib

Is it possible to access the rasterized representation of a matplotlib Artist? I know that calling `set_rasterized(True)` will produce rasterized figure export. However, I have not found a way to access this bitmap directly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that the rasterisation only takes place upon actually *rendering* the figure, I think the easiest solution is a two-step progress where you'd actually store the raster image to file and the load it again:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.image as mpimg

## create a figure, here 72 dpi at 10 inch figure size yields 720x720px
fig = plt.figure(frameon=False,dpi=72,figsize=(10,10))
## make the axis full size
ax = plt.Axes(fig, [0., 0., 1., 1.])
ax.set_aspect(1)
fig.add_axes(ax)

## actually plot something that has obviously transparent regions,
#  e.g. a rectangular shape that's twisted by 45 degrees
d = np.arange(100).reshape(10, 10)
x, y = np.meshgrid(np.arange(11), np.arange(11))
theta = 0.25*np.pi
xx = x*np.cos(theta) - y*np.sin(theta)
yy = x*np.sin(theta) + y*np.cos(theta)

## make sure you've rasterized the artist
m = ax.pcolormesh(xx, yy, d)
m.set_rasterized(True)
ax.set_axis_off()

## store the image
plt.savefig("/tmp/test.png")

## load the image
img = mpimg.imread("/tmp/test.png")
print(img.shape) # this should now be (720,720,4), i.e. an RGBA image 
print(img[:1,:1])# this should be [[[1. 1. 1. 0.]]] ,i.e. a white, 100% transparent pixel
```

*Note:* there may be nicer solutions to it, but hey, it works :-)

### Update:

What you can do to access the image "directly" is to draw the canvas (e.g. via `plt.show()` and then read the buffer:

```
# … the initial plotting code from above goes here
plt.show()
s, (width, height) = fig.canvas.print_to_buffer()
print(width,height) ## in my case with a high-dpi display this yields 1440x1440 !
X = np.frombuffer(s, np.uint8).reshape((height, width, 4))
print(X.shape)
```

Which should yield (720,720,4) but in my case is (1440, 1440, 4) due to my retina display. To circumvent this, you could use:

```
from matplotlib.backends.backend_agg import FigureCanvasAgg

# … plotting code goes here
canvas = FigureCanvasAgg(fig)

# code from update goes here:
X = np.frombuffer(s, np.uint8).reshape((height, width, 4))
print(X.shape)
# now yields (720, 720, 4)
```

Comment: I have tried this, and it sorta works ... But I have discovered this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21939658/matplotlib-render-into-buffer-access-pixel-data In more recent versions of matplotlib, `fig.canvas.tostring_rgba()` can be used to get a buffer that can be fed back to numpy using `np.frombuffer()` ! I am currently investigating this.