# Layering two images without saving them to disk first

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am trying to add a Matplotlib plot (with a transparent background) to every frame from a video stream.

This works:

```
        figure.savefig("img/plot.png", bbox_inches=bbox, transparent=True)
        img2 = Image.open("img/plot.png").resize((self.videoWidth, self.videoHeight))
        img1.paste(img2, (0,0), mask = img2)
        imgCTk = CTkImage(light_image=img1, dark_image=img1, size=(self.videoWidth, self.videoHeight))
        self.Lbl_Image.configure(image = imgCTk)
        self.Lbl_Image.image = imgCTk
```

I would like to **avoid saving the plot image to disk** just to reread it and paste it on the video frame. Is there a way to “save” the plot to a variable and use it afterward the same way? Writing and reading a file to disk seems sloppy and also slows down the program.

Comment: I think this question misses some context, it would be good if you provide a self contained example. Especially it depends on what the plot is. To add the plot to the video frame it needs to be rasterized, which happens exactly when saving to an image file (see https://stackoverflow.com/a/64964203/19802442). When the plot is just another image, you can maybe add it in memory.