# How to convert matplotlib.pyplot.specgram plotted image to numpy array?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am currently working on a project requires fast processing time. Thus, I am trying to find an efficient way to convert the figure plotted by plt.specgram to 3 channel numpy array [0,255]. Does any one familiar with this problem?

```
[S,Ft,T,P]=plt.specgram(a, mode='psd',scale='dB',vmax=-100,vmin=-150,window=w,noverlap=int(48*1024/64),NFFT=1024, Fs=sample_rate,cmap='hot')
```

In short, I would like to get the 3 channel [0,255] array representing the plotted image with the fastest speed(without saving fig to drive). Here P is the plt.Axesimage.

Thanks!

Comment: Have you already checked [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21939658/matplotlib-render-into-buffer-access-pixel-data)? It looks pretty similar to what you are looking for.