# How to directly read image as array from pyplot figure?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I want to read current view of pyplot figure as numpy array without saving the file and loading it.

What I tried first was to plot the data and save it and load it using imread. But I guess this save-and-load reduces task's time-efficiency.

```py
# Plotting
plt.plot(data_x, data_y, data_z)
plt.savefile('output.png')
plt.close()

# Load image as numpy array
im = cv2.read('output.png')
```

How can I change this code to do same work but increase time efficiency?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Matplotlib: save plot to numpy array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7821518/matplotlib-save-plot-to-numpy-array)

Comment: @Callin looks like it. Thx.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry to bother you. My code is to see 3D skeletal joints model (each neighbor joints are connected as line) in 3D coordinate.

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np


def draw_3D_model(file_name)
   fig = plt.figure()
   ax = plt.axes(projection = '3d')
   ax.grid(False)
   ax.view_init(azim = -90,elev = -50)

   draw_skeleton(file_name)   # this is the function I made to draw a line between neighbor joints(only used plt.plot()

   return fig


def make_animation   
   for file_name in file_names:
      fig = draw_3D_model(file_name)
      fig.canvas.draw ( )
      w,h = fig.canvas.get_width_height()
      buf = numpy.fromstring ( fig.canvas.tostring_argb(), dtype=numpy.uint8 )
      buf.shape = ( w, h,4 )
```

This is simplified structure of my code, and when doing buf.shape = ( w, h, 4 ), it shows the error message that the size of buf cannot be reshape to ( w, h, 4 ).